# How can make Api for Call sharing and group call pickup Microsoft teams?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/call-sharing-and-group-call-pickup#configure-group-call-pickup
How can make Api for Call sharing and group call pickup  Microsoft teams  ?

Comment: What do you expect Stack Overflow to do other than simply regurgitate the content of the linked documentation?

Comment: I've seen this link before. It's mentioned in the  Microsoft team's settings, while I need to write a program for it through APIs or Power Shell for a large number of users.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Call Transfer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/{id}/transfer
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 430

{
  "transferTarget": {
    "endpointType": "default",
    "identity": {
      "user": {
        "id": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx",
        "displayName": "Heidi Steen"
      }
    },
    "replacesCallId": "replacesCallId-value"
  },
  "clientContext": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx"
}
```

You could take a look into [Calling and meeting bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview).

And here are the [Graph API References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26500665)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the answer.